# How to enable Javascript?

Tags: browser, websites, javascript

Both Gmail and Chrome browser tell me I need to enable JavaScript. How do I do this. Did not find anything in Software Center.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript is a web browser's feature, not a software you can install.

If you're using Firefox, select **Preferences** in **Edit** menu, then click **Contents** icon and check **Permit JavaScript**.

Answer (score 1):

Install Google Chrome from [official source](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/). Click on "Settings" → "Show advanced settings" → "Content Settings"  → "Allow all sites to run JavaScript (recommended)"

On some versions, it could also be: "Settings" → "Privacy and security" → "Site settings" → "JavaScript" → "Allow (recommended)"

Answer (score 0):

Updating as things seem to have changed. In Firefox, JavaScript is enabled by default, because hardly anything works without JS these days.

To disable it, or check it is enabled, type `about:config` in the URL field and confirm that you are not scared of dragons.

Search for `JavaScript:enabled`. If it says **true** in the right hand column, JS is enabled.

To change the setting, click on it and then click **Toggle**. **true** will change to **false** or vice versa.

Please be careful with `about:config`. Stuff can break.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome extension for this: [Quick Javascript Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje)